# Как передать массив переменных в template?

Tags: c++

Есть функция Bingo, у нее много шаблонов, меня интересует как передать все переменные через одну переменную или массив, например будет одна переменная T1 и одна переменная T2, и в них будет целый массив, каких то переменных.

ПРИМЕР:

```
int 
a = 01,
b = 02,
c = 03,
d = 04,
e = 05,
r = 06,
p = 07;

string
z = "text",
x = "text2",
n = "text3";

template <typename T1, typename T2>
void Bingo(T1& a, T1& b, T1& c, T1& d, T1& e, T1& r, T1& p, T2& z, T2& x, T2& n)
{
    a = 777;
    // код
}

Bingo(a,b,c,d,e,r,p,z,x,n); // вызвать в main
```

Я бы хотел видеть код таким

```
void Bingo(T1& abc T2& txt)
    {
        // код
    }

Bingo(abc, txt); // вызвать в main
```

но при этом вы понимаете да, что abc на самом деле, содержит все переменные int внутри себя.

**Еще дурацкий пример (1)**

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void Bingo(T1& vec1, T2& vec2) {

    a = 777; // не работает печально конечно
}


vector<int> var{ a, b, c, d, e, r, p }; // не то что нужно и вообще это копия переменных
vector<string> var2{ z, x, n};

Bingo(var, var2);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98137/discussion-on-question-by-badbi------template).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует такая вещь как шаблон с переменным кол-вом параметров(он же variadic template).
Для применения в простых случаях требуется немного знаний о рекурсии и шаблонах.

Пример функции которая выводит на экран все что в нее передается ( любое кол-во типов, и любое кол-во передаваемых аргументов:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



template <typename T>
void print(T value) {
cout << value << endl;
}

template<class first, class ... others>
void print(first value, others ... package)
{
cout << value << endl;
print(package...);
}

void main() {
system("chcp 1251 > null");

string str1 = "шалость";
string str2 = "удалась";
int a = 55;


print(a, str1, 55.f, str2, "rrrr", 434 , "Sdsd");

system("pause");

}
```

Механизм работы вкратце и предельно простыми словами:

При вызове функции в мейне, вызывается 2 ой экземпляр функции print, в котором первый параметр first и вместо второго параметра идет пак/список параметров others... list.

Выводится на экран параметр first. Затем идет рекурсивный вызов где в качестве аргумента выступает пак list. Тут самое интересное. 
Вызывается все тот экземпляр что и в первый раз. От cписка list "отрывается" первый параметр и идет на место first, а оставшаяся часть списка остается в others... list.

Как только в списке остается один параметр, вызывается перегрузка функции print с одним параметром (та что 
c одним шаблонным параметром "Т"), выводится последний параметр и происходит выход из рекурсии.

Стоит пояснить что делает оператор "...", а именно в том месте где происходит рекурсивный вызов. Конструкция "list..." означает распаковку списка параметров, т.е вместо "list..." подставляются все параметры которые в нем хранятся через запятую.

Мозг сломать можно, согласен) Но в плюсах без этого никак.

Ну а для определения типа параметра который пришел в шаблонную функцию можно использовать RTTI.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98135/discussion-on-answer-by-uporka------template).

Comment: можно как то убрать вторую `template <typename T>
void print(T value) {
cout << value << endl;
}` и сохранить рекурсию?
Как я понял это срабатывает только в самом конце.

Comment: Это условие выхода из рекурсии на языке шаблонов. Наверное никак. При проектирование любой рекурсивной функции должно быть условие выхода. Иначе переполнение стека неминуемо.

Answer (score -2):

Убрал **union**. Передаю аргументы в виде указателя на массив. Всё работает.

```
// g++ -Wall templargs.cpp
# include <string>
using std::string;
# include <iostream>
using std::cout;

template <typename T1, typename T2>
void Bingo (T1 * args1 [],T2 * args2 []){
  for(size_t i = 0 ;args1[i];++ i) {
    (*(args1[i])) = 777 ; }
  for(size_t i = 0 ;args2[i];++ i) {
    (*(args2[i])) = "777" ; } }

struct Arg {
  enum  { Int , String  } ;
  void * arg ;
  int type ;
} ;    

void Bingo (Arg args []) {
  for(size_t i = 0 ;args[i].arg;++ i) {
    switch(args[i].type){
    case  Arg::Int  :
      (*(int*)(args[i].arg)) = 888 ;
      break;
    case  Arg::String :
      (*(string*)(args[i].arg)) = "888" ;
      break;
    default : ; } } }

int main(){
  int 
a = 0,
b = 0,
c = 0,
d = 0,
e = 0,
r = 0,
p = 0;

string
z = "text",
x = "text",
cs = "text";

  // создаёте массив аргументов, заканчивающийся пустым указателем
  int * argsi []= {&a,&b,&c,&d,&e,&r,&p,nullptr};
  string * argss[] = {&z,&x,&cs,nullptr} ;
  Bingo(argsi,argss);
  cout << "p="<<p<<"\n"<<"cs="<<cs<<"\n";

  Arg args [ ] = { { & a , Arg::Int } , { & z , Arg::String } , { nullptr , 0 } } ;
  Bingo(args);
  cout << "a="<<a<<"\n"<<"z="<<z<<"\n";

}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98161/discussion-on-answer-by-alexglebe------template).